# Kendo ui grid

Tags: jquery, json, kendo

Здравствуйте вопрос о [Kendo ui Grid](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing.html)
Поставил себе, все работает, вывод редактирование, сейчас дошел до команды delete и она работать не хочет, браузером пытаюсь отследить как запрос передается но при нажатии на кнопку, но ничего он не передает, как быть?

=============
Заметил что если **editable: true** заменить на **editable: "inline"** То отправляется Get запрос при удалении, с чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по демке, удаление только из dom происходит, но там каждой строке присваивается data-uid, элементарно, делаете ajax с этим параметром и обновляете таблицу

Comment: Я тоже так подумал, а еще думал что об этом позаботился сам Kendo ui и есть готовое решение.

Comment: Кстати вопрос очень своевременный :) я например про этот грид не знал и благодарен за альтернативу dataTables